# node.js sqlanywhere compilation/update errors

Tags: node.js, sqlanywhere

I'm trying compile/update node-sqlanywhere, but I keep getting errors. This is the verbose result when I tried to install

```
$ npm install sqlanywhere --verbose
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ 'c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   'install',
npm verb cli   'sqlanywhere',
npm verb cli   '--verbose' ]
npm info using npm@2.11.2
npm info using node@v0.12.5
npm verb install initial load of c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobileapp\package.json
npm WARN package.json mobileapp@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json mobileapp@1.0.0 No README data
npm verb installManyTop reading scoped package data from c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobile
app\node_modules\async\package.json
npm verb installManyTop reading scoped package data from c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobile
app\node_modules\bignumber.js\package.json
npm verb installManyTop reading scoped package data from c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobile
app\node_modules\body-parser\package.json
npm verb installManyTop reading scoped package data from c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobile
app\node_modules\colors\package.json
npm verb installManyTop reading scoped package data from c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobile
app\node_modules\connect\package.json
npm verb installManyTop reading scoped package data from c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobile
app\node_modules\cookie-parser\package.json
npm verb installManyTop reading scoped package data from c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobile
app\node_modules\deferred\package.json
npm verb installManyTop reading scoped package data from c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobile
app\node_modules\express\package.json
npm verb installManyTop reading scoped package data from c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobile
app\node_modules\express-session\package.json
npm verb installManyTop reading scoped package data from c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobile
app\node_modules\gcm\package.json
npm verb installManyTop reading scoped package data from c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobile
app\node_modules\minify.js\package.json
npm verb installManyTop reading scoped package data from c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobile
app\node_modules\moment\package.json
npm verb installManyTop reading scoped package data from c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobile
app\node_modules\npm-debug.log\package.json
npm verb installManyTop reading scoped package data from c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobile
app\node_modules\on-file-change\package.json
npm verb installManyTop reading scoped package data from c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobile
app\node_modules\point-in-polygon\package.json
npm verb installManyTop reading scoped package data from c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobile
app\node_modules\qs\package.json
npm verb installManyTop reading scoped package data from c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobile
app\node_modules\readable-stream\package.json
npm verb installManyTop reading scoped package data from c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobile
app\node_modules\restify\package.json
npm verb installManyTop reading scoped package data from c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobile
app\node_modules\ws\package.json
npm info package.json deferred@0.7.2 No license field.
npm info package.json gcm@1.0.1 No license field.
npm info package.json moment@2.10.3 No license field.
npm info package.json restify@3.0.3 No license field.
npm verb readDependencies loading dependencies from c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobileapp\p
ackage.json
npm verb cache add spec sqlanywhere@^1.0.3
npm verb addNamed ">=1.0.3 <2.0.0" is a valid semver range for sqlanywhere
npm verb addNameRange registry:https://registry.npmjs.org/sqlanywhere not in fli
ght; fetching
npm verb request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/sqlanywhere
npm verb request no auth needed
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 2:48:55 PM
npm verb request id 3faa3e77db0a05cc
npm verb etag "4DTDIBB7TGQ3L37QR6XV0K58D"
npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sqlanywhere
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sqlanywhere
npm verb etag https://registry.npmjs.org/sqlanywhere from cache
npm verb get saving sqlanywhere to C:\Users\didgy\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\regi
stry.npmjs.org\sqlanywhere\.cache.json
npm verb addNamed "1.0.3" is a plain semver version for sqlanywhere
npm verb afterAdd C:\Users\didgy\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\sqlanywhere\1.0.3\pac
kage\package.json not in flight; writing
npm verb afterAdd C:\Users\didgy\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\sqlanywhere\1.0.3\pac
kage\package.json written
npm info install sqlanywhere@1.0.3 into c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobileapp
npm info installOne sqlanywhere@1.0.3
npm verb installOne of sqlanywhere to c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobileapp not in flight;
installing
npm verb lock using C:\Users\didgy\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\sqlanywhere-
e7c967517ca70ed4.lock for c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobileapp\node_modules\sqlanywhere
npm verb unbuild node_modules\sqlanywhere
npm verb gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobileapp\n
ode_modules\sqlanywhere
npm verb tar unpack C:\Users\didgy\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\sqlanywhere\1.0.3\p
ackage.tgz
npm verb tar unpacking to c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobileapp\node_modules\sqlanywhere
npm verb gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobileapp\n
ode_modules\sqlanywhere
npm verb write writing to c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobileapp\node_modules\sqlanywhere\pa
ckage.json
npm info preinstall sqlanywhere@1.0.3
npm verb readDependencies loading dependencies from c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobileapp\n
ode_modules\sqlanywhere\package.json
npm verb readDependencies loading dependencies from c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobileapp\n
ode_modules\sqlanywhere\package.json
npm verb about to build c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobileapp\node_modules\sqlanywhere
npm info build c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobileapp\node_modules\sqlanywhere
npm info linkStuff sqlanywhere@1.0.3
npm verb linkBins sqlanywhere@1.0.3
npm verb linkMans sqlanywhere@1.0.3
npm verb rebuildBundles sqlanywhere@1.0.3
npm info install sqlanywhere@1.0.3

> sqlanywhere@1.0.3 install c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobileapp\node_modules\sqlanywhere
> node build.js

Looking for binaries...
Trying to build binaries
Error when executing node-gyp configure
npm verb unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
npm info sqlanywhere@1.0.3 Failed to exec install script
npm verb unlock done using C:\Users\didgy\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\sqlan
ywhere-e7c967517ca70ed4.lock for c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobileapp\node_modules\sqlanyw
here
npm verb stack Error: sqlanywhere@1.0.3 install: `node build.js`
npm verb stack Exit status 4294967295
npm verb stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_mod
ules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:213:16)
npm verb stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:110:17)
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_mod
ules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
npm verb stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
npm verb stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087
:5)
npm verb pkgid sqlanywhere@1.0.3
npm verb cwd c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobileapp
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "sqlanywhere" "--verbose"
npm ERR! node v0.12.5
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! sqlanywhere@1.0.3 install: `node build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 4294967295
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlanywhere@1.0.3 install script 'node build.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the sqlanywhere package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node build.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls sqlanywhere
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm verb exit [ 1, true ]
npm verb unbuild node_modules\sqlanywhere
npm info preuninstall sqlanywhere@1.0.3
npm info uninstall sqlanywhere@1.0.3
npm verb unbuild rmStuff sqlanywhere@1.0.3 from c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobileapp\node_
modules
npm info postuninstall sqlanywhere@1.0.3
npm verb gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobileapp\n
ode_modules\sqlanywhere

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     c:\ProgAlgo\Node\mobileapp\npm-debug.log
```

I tried to download the source and then compile it, but I got even more errors

```
node-gyp build
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@2.0.1
gyp info using node@0.12.5 | win32 | x64
gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe
gyp info spawn args [ 'build/binding.sln',
gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64' ]
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
  sqlanywhere.cpp
  utils.cpp
  sacapidll.cpp
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(135): error C2039: 'ObjectWrap' :
 is not a member of 'node' (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build
\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(135): error C2504: 'ObjectWrap' :
 base class undefined (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqla
nywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(140): error C4430: missing type s
pecifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\utils.cp
p) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(140): error C2143: syntax error :
 missing ',' before '&' (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sq
lanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(145): error C4430: missing type s
pecifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\utils.cp
p) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(145): error C2143: syntax error :
 missing ',' before '&' (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sq
lanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(135): error C2039: 'ObjectWrap' :
 is not a member of 'node' (..\src\sqlanywhere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master
\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(135): error C2504: 'ObjectWrap' :
 base class undefined (..\src\sqlanywhere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\buil
d\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(140): error C4430: missing type s
pecifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\sqlanywh
ere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(140): error C2143: syntax error :
 missing ',' before '&' (..\src\sqlanywhere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\bu
ild\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(152): error C2061: syntax error :
 identifier 'uv_work_t' (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sq
lanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(145): error C4430: missing type s
pecifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\sqlanywh
ere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(154): error C2061: syntax error :
 identifier 'uv_work_t' (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sq
lanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(145): error C2143: syntax error :
 missing ',' before '&' (..\src\sqlanywhere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\bu
ild\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(156): error C2061: syntax error :
 identifier 'uv_work_t' (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sq
lanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(158): error C4430: missing type s
pecifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\utils.cp
p) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(158): error C2143: syntax error :
 missing ',' before '&' (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sq
lanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(152): error C2061: syntax error :
 identifier 'uv_work_t' (..\src\sqlanywhere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\bu
ild\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(235): error C4430: missing type s
pecifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\utils.cp
p) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(154): error C2061: syntax error :
 identifier 'uv_work_t' (..\src\sqlanywhere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\bu
ild\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(235): error C2143: syntax error :
 missing ',' before '&' (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sq
lanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(156): error C2061: syntax error :
 identifier 'uv_work_t' (..\src\sqlanywhere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\bu
ild\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(268): error C4430: missing type s
pecifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\utils.cp
p) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(158): error C4430: missing type s
pecifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\sqlanywh
ere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(268): error C2143: syntax error :
 missing ',' before '&' (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sq
lanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(158): error C2143: syntax error :
 missing ',' before '&' (..\src\sqlanywhere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\bu
ild\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(271): error C2061: syntax error :
 identifier 'uv_work_t' (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sq
lanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(235): error C4430: missing type s
pecifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\sqlanywh
ere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(328): error C4430: missing type s
pecifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\utils.cp
p) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(235): error C2143: syntax error :
 missing ',' before '&' (..\src\sqlanywhere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\bu
ild\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(328): error C2143: syntax error :
 missing ',' before '&' (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sq
lanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(268): error C4430: missing type s
pecifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\sqlanywh
ere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(366): error C4430: missing type s
pecifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\utils.cp
p) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(268): error C2143: syntax error :
 missing ',' before '&' (..\src\sqlanywhere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\bu
ild\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(366): error C2143: syntax error :
 missing ',' before '&' (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sq
lanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(271): error C2061: syntax error :
 identifier 'uv_work_t' (..\src\sqlanywhere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\bu
ild\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(369): error C2061: syntax error :
 identifier 'uv_work_t' (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sq
lanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(328): error C4430: missing type s
pecifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\sqlanywh
ere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(371): error C2061: syntax error :
 identifier 'uv_work_t' (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sq
lanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(328): error C2143: syntax error :
 missing ',' before '&' (..\src\sqlanywhere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\bu
ild\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(414): error C4430: missing type s
pecifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\utils.cp
p) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(366): error C4430: missing type s
pecifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\sqlanywh
ere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(414): error C2143: syntax error :
 missing ',' before '&' (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sq
lanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(366): error C2143: syntax error :
 missing ',' before '&' (..\src\sqlanywhere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\bu
ild\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(416): error C2061: syntax error :
 identifier 'uv_work_t' (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sq
lanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(369): error C2061: syntax error :
 identifier 'uv_work_t' (..\src\sqlanywhere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\bu
ild\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(457): error C4430: missing type s
pecifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\utils.cp
p) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(371): error C2061: syntax error :
 identifier 'uv_work_t' (..\src\sqlanywhere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\bu
ild\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(457): error C2143: syntax error :
 missing ',' before '&' (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sq
lanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(414): error C4430: missing type s
pecifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\sqlanywh
ere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(459): error C2061: syntax error :
 identifier 'uv_work_t' (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sq
lanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(414): error C2143: syntax error :
 missing ',' before '&' (..\src\sqlanywhere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\bu
ild\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(469): error C2146: syntax error :
 missing ';' before identifier 'conn_mutex' (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanyw
here-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(416): error C2061: syntax error :
 identifier 'uv_work_t' (..\src\sqlanywhere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\bu
ild\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(469): error C4430: missing type s
pecifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\utils.cp
p) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(457): error C4430: missing type s
pecifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\sqlanywh
ere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(457): error C2143: syntax error :
 missing ',' before '&' (..\src\sqlanywhere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\bu
ild\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(459): error C2061: syntax error :
 identifier 'uv_work_t' (..\src\sqlanywhere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\bu
ild\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(469): error C2146: syntax error :
 missing ';' before identifier 'conn_mutex' (..\src\sqlanywhere.cpp) [c:\node-s
qlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\stmt.h(14): error C2039: 'ObjectWrap' : is not
 a member of 'node' (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlany
where.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\connection.h(469): error C4430: missing type s
pecifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\sqlanywh
ere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\stmt.h(14): error C2504: 'ObjectWrap' : base c
lass undefined (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhere
.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\stmt.h(19): error C4430: missing type specifie
r - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\
node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\stmt.h(19): error C2143: syntax error : missin
g ',' before '&' (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhe
re.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\stmt.h(29): error C4430: missing type specifie
r - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\
node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\stmt.h(29): error C2143: syntax error : missin
g ',' before '&' (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhe
re.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\stmt.h(75): error C4430: missing type specifie
r - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\
node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\stmt.h(14): error C2039: 'ObjectWrap' : is not
 a member of 'node' (..\src\sqlanywhere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\
sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\stmt.h(75): error C2143: syntax error : missin
g ',' before '&' (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhe
re.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\stmt.h(14): error C2504: 'ObjectWrap' : base c
lass undefined (..\src\sqlanywhere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlan
ywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\stmt.h(111): error C4430: missing type specifi
er - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:
\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\stmt.h(19): error C4430: missing type specifie
r - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\sqlanywhere.cpp
) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\stmt.h(111): error C2143: syntax error : missi
ng ',' before '&' (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywh
ere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\stmt.h(19): error C2143: syntax error : missin
g ',' before '&' (..\src\sqlanywhere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sql
anywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\stmt.h(114): error C2061: syntax error : ident
ifier 'uv_work_t' (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywh
ere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\stmt.h(29): error C4430: missing type specifie
r - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\sqlanywhere.cpp
) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\stmt.h(116): error C2061: syntax error : ident
ifier 'uv_work_t' (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywh
ere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\stmt.h(29): error C2143: syntax error : missin
g ',' before '&' (..\src\sqlanywhere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sql
anywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\utils.h(33): error C2146: syntax error : missi
ng ';' before identifier 'api_mutex' (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-ma
ster\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\stmt.h(75): error C4430: missing type specifie
r - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\sqlanywhere.cpp
) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\utils.h(33): error C4430: missing type specifi
er - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:
\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\stmt.h(75): error C2143: syntax error : missin
g ',' before '&' (..\src\sqlanywhere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sql
anywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\stmt.h(111): error C4430: missing type specifi
er - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\sqlanywhere.cp
p) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\utils.h(54): error C2061: syntax error : ident
ifier 'uv_mutex_t' (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanyw
here.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\stmt.h(111): error C2143: syntax error : missi
ng ',' before '&' (..\src\sqlanywhere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sq
lanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\utils.h(65): error C2143: syntax error : missi
ng ';' before '&' (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywh
ere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\stmt.h(114): error C2061: syntax error : ident
ifier 'uv_work_t' (..\src\sqlanywhere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sq
lanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\utils.h(65): error C4430: missing type specifi
er - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\utils.cpp) [c:
\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\stmt.h(116): error C2061: syntax error : ident
ifier 'uv_work_t' (..\src\sqlanywhere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\build\sq
lanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\utils.h(33): error C2146: syntax error : missi
ng ';' before identifier 'api_mutex' (..\src\sqlanywhere.cpp) [c:\node-sqlanywh
ere-master\build\sqlanywhere.vcxproj]
c:\node-sqlanywhere-master\src\h\utils.h(54): error C2065: 'mtx' :
```

...

Looking at the node-gyp site, I checked that I have every dependencies installed. I'm running Windows 7 x64. Python 2.7.3 is installed and I did create the PYTHON environment variable. I have Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate installed and I also installed the "Compiler update for the Windows SDK 7.1". I'm running out of idea...

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL Anywhere node.js driver currently only supports node 0.10. We are working on adding support for version 0.12 but I have no estimate on when that might be available.

**Update**: The SQL Anywhere node.js driver now supports version 0.10, 0.12, 4.x, 5.x, and 6.x.

*Disclaimer: I work for SAP in SQL Anywhere engineering.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm disappointment, but at least I know not to waste anymore time. I think this limitation should be in the prerequisites section of the readme, so others won't waste time.

Comment: @Graeme- Does SQL Anywhere node.js driver support node v4.2.6? Since I keep getting this error------>

    Failed at the sqlanywhere@1.0.13 install script 'node build.js'
    This is most likely a problem with the sqlanywhere package,
    not with npm itself.

Comment: It does but we have seen build problems on some platforms. What platform are you running on?